# Local Notification on certain days

Tags: objective-c, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I wanna repeat a local notification message every Wednesday and at 1.00 pm.

But what is with this code wrong?

**Edit**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
//Calendar
NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *dateCompnent = [gregCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateCompnent setHour:18];
[dateCompnent setMinute:03];
[dateCompnent setWeekday:3];

NSDate *date = [gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateCompnent];

//Notification
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[notification setAlertBody:@"Test Notification"];
[notification setFireDate:date];
[notification setSoundName:@"sound.mp3"];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
```

}

Comment: What exactly does not work? Are you getting no notification? Or only one?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `UIDatePicker` just to create a `UIDate` from `NSDateComponents` is a bit weird here.

You can use the `dateFromComponents` method from `NSCalendar`:

```
NSDate *date = [gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateCompnent];
```

Also, try to change your `NSDateComponents` to only the components you'll use:

```
NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *dateCompnent = [gregCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateCompnent setWeekday:4];
[dateCompnent setHour:13];
[dateCompnent setMinute:00];
```

EDIT

Not sure what is working, but my guess it's the repeating (as I do not see any code related to repeating the `UILocalNotification`)

Have a look at the class reference of `UILocalNotification` and more specifically the property [`repeatInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval)

Comment: Thanks, but it still dosen`t work. Look on edit post.

Comment: So what doesn't work? Adding a notification? The repeating of the notification? Be more specific

Comment: I set the weekday on today (3) and the time to 18:00. I closed the app and I waited, nothing happens :-(

Comment: So which value does your NSDate actually have when adding it to the UILocalNotification?

Comment: And in which timeZone are you? NSDate will always print out in GMT in the debug area. So if you are in CEST f.e. it will actually be +2 hours

Comment: You are right, I am in the CEST time zone, but how would I change that?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.. Not sure if you can change it, but there's actually no need to change it. The debugger will always show the NSDate in GMT timezone, so you just need to keep that in mind and add + 2 hours for you